# Mozilla Persona: get email address

Tags: mozilla, browserid

I feel like I'm missing something basic here, but am having trouble finding it. I simply need to access the email address that someone has used to log into Persona. I'm looking for the email address so I can pass it along as an assertion for Open Badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to get the email address out of the assertion is to simply send the assertion to the verifier: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Persona/Quick_Setup#Step_4.3A_Verify_the_user.E2.80.99s_credentials